# Query data using first 3 and last 3 characters from a ten character word

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data set of about 10K alphanumeric words with 10 characters length each. I need to match these using the first 3 characters and the last 3 characters.

Example: `BGP12BR2010`

In this case, I should use only BGP and 010 and see if there are any entries in my database. I have used

```
LEFT(replace(term_id,' ',''),3)||RIGHT(replace(term_id,' ',''),3)
```

Is there any other way to get this done.

Comment: the example shown has 11 characters?can you better explain what you mean by *I should use only BGP and 010 and see if there are any entries in my database*

Comment: The example I have used is just for indication. I have some data entries and I need to check if these entries are present in my database using the first 3 and the last 3 characters.

Comment: And what is the expected output from the specified "matching" operation. Do you want to write a query that teturn the rows that match?  Just the values of the column that match?  Just True/False a match exists?  Or 42 (a count of the number of rows that match.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTabel WHERE term_id LIKE 'BGP%210';
```

this matches on all string, not only 10 CHAR. to specify the lenght you can
use underscore

```
SELECT * FROM yourTabel WHERE term_id LIKE 'BGP____210';
```

A better way for this is to add 2 virtual **persitent** fields, where Mysql calculate the values and you also **can set a index on it** for a better performance and not using a full table scan

**add persistent virtual fields**

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD COLUMN first3 VARCHAR(5) AS (SUBSTRING('hallo',1,3)) PERSISTENT,
ADD COLUMN last3 VARCHAR(5) AS (SUBSTRING('hallo',-3,3)) PERSISTENT;
```

**Now you can select it**

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable where first in('BGP','YXZ','XXX) and last3 = '210';
```

Comment: Thanks, But the data set has different alphanumeric entries and not only BGP. Apologies if I was not clear earlier. How do I check if these entries are present in my database using only the first 3 and the last 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do so:

```
SELECT  *  FROM yourtable   
WHERE LENGTH(yourcolumn) = 10   
AND yourcolumn LIKE 'BPG%010';
```

Comment: Thanks ! The example I have used is just for indication. I have some data entries and I need to check if these entries are present in my database using the first 3 and the last 3 characters

Comment: @Kiran - i have add things in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values starting with 3 alphabets and ending with 3 numeric characters, use

```
select * 
from t 
where val regexp '^[a-z]{3}.+[0-9]{3}$'
```

To extract them, if they follow the above pattern,

```
select val, substring(val,1,3) as first3, substring(val,-3,3) last3,
--concatenate them if required
concat(substring(val,1,3), substring(val,-3,3)) concatenated_string
from t 
where val regexp '^[a-z]{3}.+[0-9]{3}$'
```

Add a condition for length of the column if it has to be exactly 10 characters. In that case, change the regexp to `'^[a-z]{3}.{numcharactersrequired}[0-9]{3}$'` , which would be `'^[a-z]{3}.{4}[0-9]{3}$'`

[**`SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/188dec/1)

Comment: Perfect, this helps. 
Can you also tell me how do I concatenate both. That would be great